# adb won't find my device when trying to install Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, tablet, adb

I am an Ubuntu 14.04 User, and I was trying to install Ubuntu on my tablet following the official instructions (https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/), but when I tried to use adb for the android backup with this command:

```
$ adb backup -apk -shared -all
```

or for unlocking the tablet with this other one:

```
$ adb reboot bootloader
```

I got this: "error: device not found".

When I write down this one:

```
& adb devices
```

I get nothing. Nevertheless, the tablet appears as connected (in the tablet and the laptop).

I was wondering if anyone knows how to solve this. I am still pretty new with Ubuntu, and I haven't found any type of solution yet although I have been trying many different options.

By the way, the tablet is a BQ Maxwell 2 Plus (with Andorid 4.1.1), if it is important to know.

Thanks!

P.D.: I tried to connect my phone too. This time with root permissions (sudo), but it was also not found (BQ Aquaris E5 HD with Android 5.0).

Comment: Have you modified the udev rules?  Also, FYI [android.stackexchange.com](http://android.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I have not modified udev rules, and I think I do not know how to do that. I am pretty much of a noob...

I have tried to modify them but I did not succeeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, finally I was able to do it on my own. I had to edit the file HOME/.android/adb_usb.ini, and add "0x2207" there (in the last line). When I plugged the tablet I used "$ adb devices" and it was there, so problem solved. I copy the link here just in case it is useful for someone else.

http://www.slatedroid.com/topic/41219-connecting-to-a-rk3066-based-board-via-adb-on-linux/

Thanks!

P.D.: udev rules where modified, but I was looking somewhere else. Thanks anyway @earthmeLon

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this solution is absolute, but you probably hadn't enabled the Android debug option available in the developer software.

Step 1 -> Go to **Parameters** -> **About Phone**, now scroll down to "**build number**" and tap **seven times** on it. This will enable Developers options and show the corresponding field in your Parameters.

Step 2 -> Go to **Parameters** -> **Developers Options**, and scroll down until you find **android debugging**. Enable it.

Your phone should now be listed when using `sudo adb devices` in terminal.